# parse kdb+ HTTP response type

Tags: kdb

I am trying to communicate with kdb+ via HTTP. I succeeded to get the the response from the DB when I did it from the browser, but for some reason, the response is neither JSON nor anything that looks machine readable.

**What I did:**

- Opened a port on `q` console (8080)
- Defined a function `getData` that gives me the data I want.

The above steps can be presented in this .q file I created:

```
\p 8080 
system["l db"] 
getData: {[a;b] ?[table;((>=;`start;$[`long;a]);(<=;`end;$[`long;b]));0b;()]}
h:hopen `:localhost:8080:user:pass
```

- I then typed `http://localhost:8080/?getData[1;2]` in the browser to get the results
- Got the results as text with spaces inside `<pre>` tag.

**The Problem**

I have no I idea how to parse it to JSON. How can I solve this? is there a way to tell kdb+ to send response in JSON format?

Comment: Can you provide *any* details on how you are attempting to do this?

Comment: @orr show code please

Comment: Where did you learn about `getdata` and how to use it?

Comment: Just to clarify, why are you opening port 8080 and then performing `hopen` on that port?

In most use cases `hopen` will provide a handle to another running q process, thus allowing for IPC of TCP/IP to take place between the two processes. In this case the process is opening a handle to itself.

Comment: @SeanHehir when I removed the `\p 8080` the `hopen` didn't work for me for some reason.

Comment: You would need to leave in the `\p` regardless, but the `hopen` may not be necessary

Answer (score 0):

**The solution I found:**

If you add `.json` before the `?` in the url (i.e. `http://localhost:8080/.json?getData[1;2]`) the response will be in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, based on your code, the following may work to return data:

```
http://localhost:8080/?getData[a;b]
```

Where `a` and `b` are start and end times (or dates, this will depend on your data).
e.g.

```
http://localhost:8080/?getData[2021.07.23;2021.07.30]
```

In order to convert a KDB+ object to json you can make use of the `.j.j` operator.
For example you can change your code to something like:

```
getData:{[a;b] t:?[table;((>=;`start;$[`long;a]);(<=;`end;$[`long;b]));0b;()];.j.j t}
```

If you want to see what the incoming request looks like on your Q process you could add some logging to `.z.ph` (the default http message handler), e.g. something like:

```
.z.ph:{[zph;x]zph 0N!x}[.z.ph]
```

This will log any incoming requests out to your q process using `0N!` and then run the usual `.z.ph` message handing code on it

Comment: yes I used the [a;b] in my code and forgot to write it down when I wrote the question.

Comment: I am trying to go with this solution, the problem is that it cuts the JSON text. how can I tell him not to cut the text? (it returns "[{\"x\":718168,...." for example)

Comment: This return is dependent on your console size. You can change this by setting `\c`. Bear in mind this will only work up to 2000 characters in the x or y direction. Some info here: https://code.kx.com/q/basics/syscmds/#c-console-size